# How to reuse a component across different application in Angular

Tags: angular, npm-install, package.json

I am having a component in Angular which i am using Across my Application.

Application A is one project which uses component 1.

Application B is another project that uses component 1

Here component 1 is the common component across two different application. How can i utilize the common component without copying the files. Can we install the component while we do npm install

Can npm install download the package of common component if we have the common component url in the package.json

Comment: This is a very good use case for implementing mono repo. You can use NX Devtools for it. If its too much, then publishing it as a separate library and including dep as peer dependency is way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Custom Angular Library, have Component 1 in it, build and publish.

Your library will be ready to be installed via npm

Check [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

I think using Bit will also do

Check here

https://codeburst.io/sharing-components-between-angular-applications-using-bit-707654263785